# Probabilistic Bound on Random Walk with Drift

Tags: probability, statistics, finance, random-walk, upper-lower-bounds

For Gaussian random variable $\xi_t$ with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, consider the random walk with initial condition $P_0=100$, such that

\begin{equation}
P_t=P_{t-1}(1+\xi_t).
\end{equation}

At time $t$, what is the probability that $P_t<k$? Or what is the probability that $P_t<100$? Any help would be much appreciated. Note that the expected value of $P_t$ is trivially $100(1+\mu)^t$.

Comment: Why would, e.g., the random variable $P_t$ be integrable?  Clearly the infinite product $\prod_{n=-\infty}^t (1+\xi_n)$ almost surely does not converge.

Comment: $P_t$ is discrete (not continuous). A possible approach would be to find the variance of $P_t$ and then use Chebyshev's inequality to establish a percentage for a value occurring outside of the variance bounds. If $\xi_t$ had mean $0$, then the variance is $t\sigma^2$ (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159650/why-does-the-variance-of-the-random-walk-increase).

Comment: Product of normal variables are complicated.  Anyway, now that you impose a deterministic $P_0$ we only have finite products to deal with, but still even the product of two independent (noncentral) normals is a difference of (noncentral) $\chi^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Note that $\xi_t$ has the same mean and standard deviation, which are constant for all $t$ (i.e. we only have one distribution). We are selecting values randomly from the distribution at time $t$. Can a variance be calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, observe that the variance of $P_t$ satisfies
$$\mathsf{Var}\, P_t=\mathsf{Var}\left(100\prod_{i=1}^t (1+\xi_i)\right)=10000\left(\mathsf{E}\left[\prod_{i=1}^t (1+\xi_i)^2\right]-\mathsf{E}\left[\prod_{i=1}^t (1+\xi_i)\right]^2\right).$$
And by independence (I assume) of the increments,
$$\mathsf{Var}\, P_t=10000\left((1+2\mu+\mu^2+\sigma^2)^t-(1+\mu)^{2t}\right)=m_t^2\left(\left(1+\frac{\sigma^2}{m_t}\right)^t-1\right),$$

where $m_t=100(1+\mu)^t$ is the expectation of $P_t$. Note that you can further estimate $\mathsf{Var}\, P_t$ if you have additional information on $\sigma$ and $\mu$ or if you are interested in the asymptotic behavior as $t\to\infty$.

From there you can apply Chebychev inequality, but note that it does not concentrate much. For example, in the case $\mu=0$, the variance grows like $(1+C)^t$ for some $C>0$ as $t\to\infty$. You can get corresponding anticoncentration with Paley-Zygmund inequality.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. If $\mu$ varied with time, would $\text{Var}(P_t)$ still be given by the new expectation (i.e. when the expectation $m_t\neq 100(1+\mu)^t$ does the formula still hold)?

Comment: Otherwise, can $\text{Var}(P_t)$ be defined in terms of $E[P_t]$?